Laravel multiple relatinships on same models
I would like users to be able to give each other ratings. I am unsure which relationship to use and how to do it correctly. Will one-to-many work best in this case since a rating is given by a user to another user?
This is what I have so far:
User:
public function ratings(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Rating::class);
}

Rating:
public function users(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

Migration:
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('ratings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();

        $table->integer('rating');

        $table->foreignId('user_id');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

I am unsure about the whole relationship since a rating is both given by a user but also given to a user. How do I differ from giving and receiving user?

You need to add an extra column and add the user that gives the rating, else you are adding a number (rating) that makes no sense are you are rating nothing. Let's say, ratings has user_id and that is who rated, and then you have rated_user_id, done

You can add another column on ratings table with the ID of the user that created the rating.
$table->foreignId('user_id');      // user ID receiving the rating
$table->foreignId('created_by');   // user ID that created the rating

Rating:
public function user(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function createdBy(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'created_by');
}

